# Win32 account SID lookup if user and group have the same name?

Tags: winapi, sid

How can I get the SID for either user XOR group if both have the same name?

Remember Unix and Linux allow that a user "danfsh" can have his own group "danfsh".
That works fine there, but on Win32 there is only LookupAccountSidA() which has no way to distinguish whether you want a user SID or a group SID.

How can I get the SID for group "danfsh", or the SID for user "danfsh", without getting the wrong type of SID?

I already tried LookupAccountSidA(), and I only get the user SID, even if there is a group with the same name but different SID.

Comment: NetGroupGetInfo() and NetUserGetInfo()

Comment: Have you used the APIs provided by Luke successfully?